# Are there any good free or cheap tools for building an Oracle Database diagram?

Tags: oracle

I need to diagram an oracle database and I am hoping to find some good tools that are either cheap, or free.

Ideally the tool should allow me to draw the relationships between the tables, as well as remove unwanted tables from the diagram.

I already have access to MS Visual Studio 2008 as well as SSMS 2008, but I don't believe either will provide much help with oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd used [Power Architect](http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect) for this. It is Open Source/GPL

Answer (score 1):

the perl sqlt program from the  [SQLFairy](http://sqlfairy.sourceforge.net/)  project (aka SQL::Translator) can read a database schema from a text file (or by directly querying the database using perl DBI) and translate the schema into a variety of formats, including some graphical/documentation formats such as Diagram and GraphViz and HTML.

it supports several different database backends, including Mysql, Postgresql, Sybase, and Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good article [here](http://www.dbasupport.com/oracle/ora10g/case02.shtml) on creating an Oracle schema diagramme in Visio.

There is also the opensource alternative to Visio, [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia).

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model#ER_diagramming_tools):

Some free software ER diagramming tools that can interpret and generate ER models, SQL and do database analysis are StarUML, MySQL Workbench, and SchemaSpy. Some free software diagram tools just draw the shapes without having any knowledge of what they mean, nor do they generate SQL. These include Kivio and Dia. DIA diagrams, however, can be translated with tedia2sql.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to MS Access, you can create an ODBC connection to the DB and then link all your tables and use the relationship builder inside Access to build the diagram. This is typically what I do, as while it is not the best method, it sure is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle just started to offer one.

Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler:

http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/datamodeler/index.html

Comment: I like the native option much better. I see they JUST release it about a month ago. Very nice.